# Color replacement GDI C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

### Replace bitmap black pixels with transparency GDI C#

---

Hey guys, Im just working on a 2d engine that renders sprites. And I need to replace de black pixels in the bitmaps with transparency; so that the bitmap below is seen.

Is this possible in GDI+ ? How? Because I've been trying with ColorMaps & Attributes and is not working fine.

As it is a 2D engine for a game, is it an efficient library? Or should I use another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
bm.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
```

GDI+ is not the best solution for a game. So far your game does not require high performance you can use it. But when it needs some power, you have to use libraries like OpenGL or Direct2D/Direct3D.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give those libraries you mention a try!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
```

As far as efficient library for a game?  In most cases, no.  GDI+ was designed more for line of business applications.